# Conditional Pointcut expression

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, aspectj

I want to enable/disable an aspect based on some property from my database. How can I do that?

Also I am using AspectJ LTW, but when I tried using if() in @Pointcut it shows a warning but code compiles fine. I don't want to go that way. Also, I don't want to make my Aspect a component and use Conditional property because then I would have to pick the property from property file.
This is a rough snippet of my code.

```java
@Aspect
class A {
  boolean flag = //get value from DB; 
    
  @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.sample..check(..)) && if())
  public boolean conditional() {
    return flag==true ? true : false;
  }
    
  @Before("conditional()")
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

aop.xml

```xml
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name = "com.sample.aspect.A"/>
    <weaver>
      <include within = "com.sample..*"/>
    </weaver>
  </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Comment: thanks for telling us the things you don't want. What is it you do want and where is your sample code? Why would you need to make your aspect a component if you use Aspect? It is only necessary for Spring AOP. But actually both Spring AOP and AspectJ support the `if()` pointcut designator. You can put any type of code into that method. I don't really get what the problem is.

Comment: attached my sample code. I want to run my Aspect based on a property from database. I tried using if() and it actually worked but I am using IntelliJ and it is showing me error as "if pointer designator not supported by spring".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `if pointcut designator isn't supported by Spring` in IntelliJ IDEA tells you the truth for Spring AOP aspects. It kicks in automatically if you use an aspect in a Spring project.

In your case the aspect is a native AspectJ aspect though, not a Spring AOP aspect. IDEA does not understand that, so the solution for your problem is not to change your approach but to just **ignore the error message** in the editor because what you are doing with `if()` is correct.

Alternatively, you can also tell IDEA to **suppress Spring AOP error inspection** for a method or a whole class:

[image]

For example, after you select "Suppress for class", the error will go away and you will see the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("SpringAopErrorsInspection")` on top of your class. That should give you some peace of mind. Please note, however, that this will also potentially suppress other Spring AOP syntax errors which would apply to AspectJ too, because Spring AOP pointcut syntax is basically a subset of AspectJ syntax.